# Source and Test "source" directories - how can I run tests from Test against Source

Tags: ant, junit

I've got a Java project which has a 'src' directory for code directly related to my project, and a 'test' directory which is JUnit tests that run against code in the 'src' directory. The directory structures are like this:

```
ROOT/src/com/mycompany/decoders/qDecoder/.....

ROOT/test/com/mycompany/decoders/qDecoder/.....
```

Both directories have the exact same package structure.

The following is the target and related JUnit info:

```
<property name="src_classes_dir" value="./bin"/>
<property name="test_classes_dir" value="./binTest"/>

<path id="junit.classpath">
  <pathelement location="${src_classes_dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${test_classes_dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/JUnit/junit.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/JavaMail/mailapi.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/JavaMail/smtp.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/CommonsLang3/commons-lang3.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/JDBC/inetsoftware/merlia/8.0.2/Merlia.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${CommonJarPath}/JodaTime/joda-time.jar"/>
</path>

<property name="test_dir" value="./test"/>  

<target name="junit" description="Run JUnit tests" depends="compile_source, compile_test">        
  <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes" haltonerror="yes" showoutput="yes">
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="no"/>
    <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>                
    <batchtest>         
      <fileset dir="${test_dir}" />
    </batchtest>    
  </junit>
</target>
```

So, my test files `(*.java)` are in `${test_dir}`. The test classes are in the `${test_classes_dir}` and the tested classes are in `${src_classes_dir}`. Both are listed in the `junit.classpath` reference.

All of the targets are completed, 'clean', 'prep', 'src_compile', and 'test_compile' up to the 'junit' target, then I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on the very first test `AMCiBitsTest`. So it knows about the test, but for some reason cannot find its class.

Here's the exception trace:

```
junit:
    [junit] Testsuite: com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    [junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    [junit]
```

**I'm stumped. What am I doing wrong? Why can't this run the `AMCiBitsTest` test and all of the other tests?**

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace of the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: try setting `<fileset dir="${test_dir}" />` to `<fileset dir="${test_classes_dir}" />` apparently there are your compiled test classes. not sure if it solves you problem.

Comment: Did you compile your _test_ code? You have to compile the `*.java` to `*.class` in your test source before you can run JUnit on them.

Comment: David W. - yes, I have a 'compile_src' and a 'compile_test' targets that this target depends on.

Comment: @Stefan Birkner:'
junit:
    [junit] Testsuite: com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]
    [junit] Caused an ERROR
    [junit] com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amci.util.AMCiBitsTest
    [junit]    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)'

Comment: @csoroiu: I did what you suggested and got the exact same error I've been getting the whole time.

Comment: I've fixed it. Suffice it to say that I made a syntax error in my build file, and what is posted above actually *does* work.            My apologies, and thanks for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. Suffice it to say that I made a syntax error in my build file, and what is posted above actually DOES WORK. My apologies, and thanks for your questions and your time.